# Any video recording software capable of capturing fullscreen opengl games on windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, screen-recording, opengl

OBS supports only windowed/borderless OpenGL games.

Same is with Radeon recording software(I have radeon gpu).

Windows built-in recording software(Xbox game bar) does not support it(It actually suggests running application in windowed/borderless mode)

If I want to record using any of above programs I have to ran application in borderless mode
I can't run game in borderless mode since it does not support it(old game).

Any programs which can record OpenGL games in fullscreen?